# How can I get_post_meta() in the most efficient way?

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta

I have a custom post type for a real estate site, and the theme displays 9 properties in a grid on the home page. I don't think its written terribly efficiently - I'm getting about 160 queries on the front page, and only about 20 of those queries are from plugins, so the theme needs some improvement.

In the first place, it includes a file in the post loop - I'm not a PHP expert, but is including the same file repeatedly in the post loop really the best thing to do?

The file that is included simply calls get_post_meta() for about a dozen or so variables for the custom post property listing (eg, number of bedrooms, etc). My first proposal is to move that section of code into the main file so its not "included" over and over.

But more importantly, is there a better way to get the post meta than to call get_post_meta() a dozen times for a dozen variables - perhaps with a single query that gets all the meta at once, which I can assign to an array?

Comment: It really depends what is in that include, including over and over isn't necessarily bad, it depends what code is being repeated over(though i'll admit there's usually a better way than repeating an include).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`get_post_custom()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom) which will return an array of all post meta in one single call to the database, that should  save a few calls.

And as for including the file over and over you could use [`get_template_part()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) to include a file once which will hold the entire loop (a good example can be found in the default twenty ten or eleven theme).

Comment: Thanks - I rewrote my code to use both your suggestions. It didn't seem to reduce the number of queries though?

Comment: Then i can only guess they come from somewhere else, try installing debug bar and see what these queries are.